# Setting variable from .CTP view to .JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

I'm having an extremely annoying and non-sense problem, are you prepared? :x

Ok, let's go:

Actualy I have an specific software deployed into 4 environments : Development, Certification, Preproduction and Production.

Yesterday I've received an error report in Production environment.

Thing is when I try to set a javascript variable from my .ctp to my .js my .js cant access that variable so the 'set' is not done. The weird thing is that in other environments (DES, CERT and PRE) that works perfectly but in PRO (for a certain casuistic it fails).

**Sketching the problem:**

- **translate.ctp**

  ```
  <?php
  $translations = array();
  $translations['NO_DATA']=__('NODATA');
  $translations['VALUE']=__('VAL');
  $translations['WEBROOT'] = $this->webroot;

  $this->Js->set('translations',$translations); // <-- prepare 'translations' into JS as window.app.translations


  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false)); // sets the variable 'translations' into the javascript (I only use writeBuffer once in this code and project)
  ?>
  ```
- **default.ctp**

...headers, script loads and stuff...

```
<?php echo $this->element('translate');?> // loads translations ctp
<?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>
```

- **main.js**

  ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
              // window.app doesn't exists so the following instruction will trigger an error:
              var translatedNoData = window.app.translations['NO_DATA'];
   }
  ```

Thank you very much guys, I hope the info above is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating this post in order to solve the 'issue' posted above.

**The code above is OK.** **$this->Js->set..** and **$this->Js->writeBuffer** are the correct way to set a variable from .CTP directly into the .JS as a global variable (it's gonna be set inside window.app)

Problem was caused by data inserted by the user. He putted some ' without closing it in a certain column from DB table which content was rendered directly into an HTML DOM element, so it crushed everything coming next...

Sry for the missunderstanding :)